# Karaf 3.0.3 add system.properties --> karaf.lock.level, leads to java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

When i add to apache-karaf-3.0.3\etc\system.properties the property karaf.lock.level=50 
the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error installing bundle listed in startup.properties with url: mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-aether/2.3.0 and startlevel: 5
at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.installAndStartBundles(Main.java:392)
at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:245)
at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.main(Main.java:167)
```

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn [1]: Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j)(version>=1.6.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.installAndStartBundles(Main.java:389)
    ... 2 more

same result when configuring the failover mechanism as described in the documentation. http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/failover.html

```
karaf.lock=true
karaf.lock.class=org.apache.karaf.main.lock.DefaultJDBCLock
karaf.lock.level=50
karaf.lock.delay=10
karaf.lock.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/something
karaf.lock.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
karaf.lock.jdbc.user=aUser
karaf.lock.jdbc.password=aUnsecurePassword
karaf.lock.jdbc.table=KARAF_LOCK
karaf.lock.jdbc.clustername=karaf
karaf.lock.jdbc.timeout=30
```

the driver is dropped to apache-karaf-3.0.3\lib\ext
when karaf.lock.level is removed or set to greater than 0 and lower than 5 it seems to work.

when i set the same lock.level.property to 50 in a 2.3.3 installation of karaf everything seems to work just fine.
does anyone know what changed there from 3.x.x to 2.3.3 or what could cause the problem.

best regards and thank you for your time :D

Comment: best to ask at the karaf mailinglist, and/or open a bug at the karaf jira

Comment: created issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-3514 and asked on mailinglist http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Karaf-3-0-3-etc-system-properties-karaf-lock-level-50-RuntimeException-on-startup-td4038298.html